# Qual é a etimologia da palavra "zaragatoa"?

Tags: etimologia

Gostaria de saber qual é a etimologia da palavra "zaragatoa", que tem ganho alguma popularidade nestes tempos difíceis da epidemia.

Nada encontrei sobre a sua etimologia nas pesquisas que realizei.
Sei o seu significado, mas não entendo a construção da palavra.

O termo que conheço que mais se assemelha a este é "zaragata", mas o seu significado nada parece ter a ver com "zaragatoa".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/zaragatoa):

> za.ra.ga.to.a
>   Do árabe vulgar *zarqatúnâ*, "caroço de algodão", pelo castelhano *zaragatona*, "idem"

Comment: Sendo assim, "zaragata" e "zaragota" muito provavelmente não devem ter nenhuma relação entre si, já que segundo https://origemdapalavra.com.br/pergunta/etimologia-de-zaragata/ zaragata vem do antigo francês "eschirgate".

Comment: @ÉlioPereira De fato, parece convergência aleatória.

Comment: za.ra.ga.to.a  fonetica :zɐrɐɡɐˈtoɐ
nome feminino
1. pequena haste ou vareta com uma porção de material absorvente numa das extremidades, que se usa para efetuar colheitas de exsudados, aplicar colutórios, etc.

Comment: @ClMend Penso que o significado da palavra já era conhecido.